# Can this group exist?

Tags: group-theory

A group that contains elements $a$ and $b$ where $a^{2} = e$ and $b^{2} = e$, $e$ is the identity element, and the order of $ab$ is infinite.  Can this group exist or can someone think of a group that fits this description?  I was thinking of using some sort of shape where $a^{2} = e$ and $b^{2} = e$ ($a$ and $b$ would be symmetries) and when doing n operations of $ab$ on the shape you never go back to the identity, but I could not come up with one.

For example, $a$ could be a reflection about an axis, and $b$ could be a reflection about another axis. However, I cannot figure out how to make $ab$ of order infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the group of bijections of $\mathbb R$ generated by the maps $$x\mapsto -x$$ and $$x\mapsto 1-x.$$

Comment: This is the so called infinite dihedral group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Just to clarify this group cannot be abelian because ab does not equal ba.  where a and b are the two maps you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be the set of the words $\{1, a, b, ab, ba, aba, bab, \ldots\}$ Suppose that the words of length $n-1$ are already defined then the words of length $n$ are obtained by adding $a$ to a length $n-1$ word that ends on a $b$, or adding $b$ to a length $n-1$ word that ends on an $a$ . Define the group operation as the concatenation of such words (after occasional simplifying the order $2$ relations) then you can verify that this is indeed a valid group operation. Note that the inverse of a word is its reverse.